# Workaround NotFound using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

If someone doesn't have a profile picture, a NotFound exception kicks me out of the code. How can I work around this?

My Method:

```cs
if(graphManager.Client.Users[user.Id].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync().IsNull())
{
    Debug.Log("profilepicture not found");
}
else
{
    var photo = await graphManager.Client.Users[mitarbeiter.Id].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();`
}
```

Response: It skips the if cause it thinks it's not null

What I need is a Method to create a Debug.Log if the exception happens and not throw me out

Answer (score 1):

It seems that getting an exception when a photo is not found is a valid case. See [docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/errors.md) on errors.

Try to handle it in the following way:

```cs
try
{
    Stream photoContent = await graphManager.Client.Users[user.Id].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
}
catch (ServiceException ex) when (ex.IsMatch(GraphErrorCode.ItemNotFound.ToString()))
{
    Debug.Log("profilepicture not found");
}
```

P.S. I'm not sure precisely which [GraphErrorCode](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Enums/GraphErrorCode.cs) should be used here.

Comment: I think in general OP should simply print out the `Debug.Log($"error: {exception}");` so it should be simple to find out what's going wrong

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the library you are using but is it possible that in the moment you do

```
graphManager.Client.Users[user.Id].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync().IsNull()
```

what happens is you are basically doing

```
var asyncResult = graphManager.Client.Users[user.Id].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
if(asyncResult.IsNull())
```

which of course would be true since you didn't give it any time to actually perform the request and finish.

It should probably rather be

```
var photo = await graphManager.Client.Users[mitarbeiter.Id].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
if(photo.IsNull() )
{ 
    Debug.Log("profilepicture not found"); 
} 
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Task<ProfilePhoto> in MS Graph SDK does not have any sort of IsNull, and it would not help anyway since it throws an exception.

Comment: @Luk164 I don't know the type.. I can only work with what OP provided and they didn't seem to get a compiler but rather runtime error...